# Why is NodeJS faster than Rust in computing the sum of the primes?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rust, benchmarking, v8

I wrote a benchmark that calculates the sum of the first 10000 primes and compared Rust to JavaScript. JavaScript on NodeJS is the fastest among Rust, Scala, and Java. Even though the programs intentionally use a functional style for testing primality aiming to show the advantages of Rust's zero-cost abstraction, NodeJS beats them all.

How can NodeJS, a dynamic typing runtime, be so fast?

**Rust code**

```rust
fn sum_primes(n: usize) -> u64 {
    let mut primes = Vec::new();
    let mut current: u64 = 2;
    let mut sum: u64 = 0;

    while primes.len() < n {
        if primes.iter().all(|p| current % p != 0) {
            sum += current;
            primes.push(current);
        }
        current += 1;
    }
    sum
}
```

**JavaScript code**

```js
function sumPrimes(n) {
    let primes = [];
    let current = 2;
    let sum = 0;
    while (primes.length < n) {
        if (primes.every(p => current % p != 0)) {
            sum += current;
            primes.push(current);
        }
        ++current;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

The full benchmark can be found [on GitHub](https://github.com/Jason5Lee/primes_benchmark).

Comment: Node can JIT compile javascript into native instructions. The further optimisations that it can apply will be _different_ from those applied by other languages, and in some cases can be faster. This question comes up a lot and the answer really is just that Node can optimise certain kinds of code very well.

Comment: I disagree with the close votes, in particular with "primarily opinion based". What about this is opinion based? Explaining this behavior requires some analysis of the code and explanation on how Rust and NodeJS optimize code. And yes, maybe the benchmark is flawed, but that can be properly explained in an answer.

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt, Re: your edit, while it would be good if the question included the relevant code, what you have added in your edit excludes the part which causes JS to be faster than Rust in this case

Comment: @ııı Mh good point. Feel free to edit the question to include more code. :)

Comment: @Jason: did you run your test on an Intel CPU?  See my comments on Denys' answer: an AMD CPU would probably not have slowed down from using unnecessarily large operand-size for the `div` instruction, with the same input data.  (Unlike pretty much all other ALU operations, div performance is data-dependent, but also slower best-case for 64-bit operand-size on Intel.)

Comment: Late to the party, but measuring each invocation individually for such a small amount of execution time will just add up clock errors. Not all languages use the same system clocks, some even decrease the precision (ie. JS, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now#examples) ). It's good training to try writing benchmark code, but always use tried and tested frameworks to compare. And even then, it's more often than not translatable to real world apps.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The answer can't be simple because V8 does a **lot** of transformations, but here's a major point:

Node's optimizing compiler dynamically adapts the types it uses (especially for array elements). It's able to use one word integers when they fit (and *deoptimizes* the function when it receives a non fitting value).

If I take your functions as they are, the Rust one takes 1.28ms to compute `sum_prime(500)` when Node takes only 1.04ms (after some warming). If I change the `u64` to `u32` in the Rust code, then it only takes 608µs.

---

The JavaScript code I used:

```js
function sum_primes(n) {
    var primes = [];
    var current = 2;
    var sum = 0;
    while (primes.length < n) {
        if (primes.every(function (p) { return current % p != 0; })) {
            sum += current;
            primes.push(current);
        }
        ++current;
    }
    return sum;
}
console.log(sum_primes(200));
// some warming
for (let i=0; i<100; i++) sum_primes(100);
console.time("primes");
console.log(sum_primes(500));
console.timeEnd("primes");
```

This JavaScript code is faster than your Rust code, but slower than this one:

```rust
use std::time::Instant;

fn sum_primes(n: usize) -> u32 {
    let mut primes = Vec::new();
    let mut current: u32 = 2;
    let mut sum: u32 = 0;

    while primes.len() < n {
        if primes.iter().all(|p| current % p != 0) {
            sum += current;
            primes.push(current);
        }
        current += 1;
    }
    sum
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", sum_primes(200));
    let s = Instant::now();
    println!("{}", sum_primes(500));
    println!("duration: {:?}", s.elapsed());
}
```

Comment: Does using `Int32Array` in JS improve its results?

Comment: Presumably you and the OP were testing on Intel CPUs, where 64-bit `div` is much slower than 32-bit `div`, even for the same small-ish dividend/divisor.  On AMD CPUs, the worst-case throughput and latency gets worse for larger operand-sizes (because larger inputs are possible), but the best case stays about the same. (https://agner.org/optimize/).  See  [Trial-division code runs 2x faster as 32-bit on Windows than 64-bit on Linux](//stackoverflow.com/a/52558274) for a specific example where *just* changing the `div` operand-size gives a huge speedup.

Comment: @PeterCordes yes. What should be remembered here isn't a specific way to optimize a terrible algorithm, or a relevant comparaison of whole languages performances, but that V8's optimizing compiler is an amazing piece of technology and that it's not enough to choose a fast language to get a fast code.

Comment: Yeah, opportunistically using a narrower type is a fantastic optimization, especially for an array.  Ahead-of-time optimizers like gcc and LLVM sometimes manage to use narrower operand-size in registers depending on value-range knowledge (like `foo & 0x1111` is known to be safe for 32-bit, even for `uint64_t foo`), but not always. And I wouldn't count on it when it really matters (like for integer division).  Languages are *capable* of being fast, but it's generally possible to write slow code in any language.  Lower-level languages can let you gain more by knowing more about the target uarch.

Answer (score -3):

I think your benchmark is somewhat flawed in that a sufficiently advanced compiler could just optimise `sum_primes(10000)` into `496165411`, even at compile-time (i.e. [Prepack](https://prepack.io/), [Closure](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/)). It is also possible to memoise the result after the first call at run-time, and probably this is what V8 does (although I would expect HotSpot to do the same).

Use a value that is not known at compile time instead of `10000`, for example a command line argument.

Comment: I tested with a command line argument, it didn't cause any changes in the results.